# Quick question about ES6 spread operator on objects

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

I just have a brief question about using spread operators on objects, when we are trying to return a copy of the object with a field changed. I've been working through a PluralSight tutorial having a lot to do with React and Redux, and I've run into this usage of the spread operator:

```
let original = {name: 'Joel', favoriteFood: 'oranges', age: 26};
let happyBirthday = {...original, age: 27};
```

Obviously this isn't the exact code from the example, but that is the usage I'm a little confused by. My initial understanding would be that this would result in an object with two `age` keys, which obviously doesn't work. Does this work by just overwriting the value of the key that's duplicated? Could I say:

```
let obj = {a: 2, a: 'no actually 3', a: 'nevermind...', a: 2};
```

And then have `obj.a` be `2`? This is a very small clarification that I'm looking for but I was thrown off when I saw this for some reason! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it overwrites the key. You don't want copies of the same key.

Comment: Open your browser console and type `var x = {a:1, b:2, c:3, c:4}; x;` and see what it outputs.  Some times the easiest way to determine behaviour is just to try things.

Comment: same key will be replaced by the latter one. if you do this, ```let obj = {a: 2, a: 'no actually 3', a: 'nevermind...', a: 3};```. obj.a will be 3

Comment: It will overwrite them in order listed in code.  This is a common trick to provide a default object, the spread it into a new one combined with passed parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects cannot have duplicate keys. If you assign a key to an object when that object already has said key, or write an object initializer with duplicate keys, the prior value at that key will be overwritten:

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
};

obj.foo = 'new';
console.log(obj);
```

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
  foo: 'new',
};

console.log(obj);
```

When using object spread, the same sort of thing is going on. If you add a key-value pair when a prior key already exists in the object initializer (by spread or otherwise), the prior value will be overwritten.

```
let happyBirthday = {...original, age: 27};
```

is very similar to

```
// Create a new object with all properties of `original`:
let happyBirthday = Object.assign({}, original);
// Assign to the `age` property of the new object:
happyBirthday.age = 27;
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for being so clear! I figured that there was overwriting going on that amount to the same result as in that final example, I guess in my head I was thinking of somehow the object being created "all at once", which doesn't really make any sense!

Answer (score 6):

```
let original = {name: 'Joel', favoriteFood: 'oranges', age: 26};
let happyBirthday = {...original, age: 27};
```

`happyBirthday` will be an object that is identical to `original` but with the `age` overwritten.

So that would result in an object like this:

```
{name: 'Joel', favoriteFood: 'oranges', age: 27} // Notice the age
```

Comment: I think you mean the age will be overwritten. Would be good to show the output too.